# Device Layout Does Not match Simulator or Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, storyboard

I've been away from Xcode for a while, so I  may have missed changes in the latest couple of releases. The layout of views looks identical in the Storyboard, and on the simulators (iPhone6 and iPhone7), but different on my iPhone 6. I have no warnings or errors in the Storyboard, and I am using Xcode 8. The device acts as if it had a shorter screen than the simulator -- things that are spread appropriately on the storyboard or simulator, are squeezed together vertically on my phone. What is the reason for this difference?

Comment: The IB gets buggy sometimes, try selecting your storyboard, then bellow where it says "View as" select iPhone 4, then select iPhone 7 plus. Now check if your layout stills looks okay, if it didn't auto resize properly you have an issue with your constraints, if it did auto resize properly save your storyboard and try it again on your device (this should un-stuck your layout). Just to be sure i recommend Cleaning your project (shift+command+k) and deleting the app from the device before building again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you assigned launch images with the correct dimensions for the different form factors? An easy way to verify this is to add a print statement in a view controller to see what the bounds are for the screen. Verify that these values match what you expect for the device.

The following from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/) documents this:

> Because device screen sizes vary, launch screen sizes vary too. To
>   accommodate this, you can provide a launch screen as an Xcode
>   storyboard or as a set of static images for the devices your app
>   supports. Using an Xcode storyboard is the recommended approach, as
>   storyboards are flexible and adaptable.

While not an official Apple site, [this link](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/launchImages.html) also references this as a potential issue:

> The launch XIB or storyboard is required to support iPhone 6 sized
>   apps.

Another possibility is that you have the screen zoomed in on the device. To change this, go to **Settings** > **Display & Brightness** and select **Display Zoom** at the bottom. Ensure that you have Standard selected. If you are zoomed in, then the device will scale down (A 6 behaves like an SE, a Plus behaves like a 6/7).

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that the phone's screen was zoomed. I'm not sure how it got that way, I don't remember doing that, but I may have when I first got the phone, and forgot about it.

Comment: @rdelmar Cool, we had an SDET with this issue that took us a while to nail down too.

Comment: Wow. I had absolutely no idea I had been running in zoomed mode since I bought the phone.